# How to prove this equation for $C_P-C_V$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

$$C_P - C_V = T \Bigg( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \Bigg)_V \Bigg( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \Bigg)_P$$

I have started with knowledge that $C_P = \Big(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial T}\Big)_P$ and $C_V = \Big(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial T}\Big)_V$ where $dQ = dU+pdV$. But I am not able to bring in the required form.

Comment: Start with $C_P=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$ and $C_V=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$